# SQL show closest available date within 30 days from a range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that returns all admissions for a particular patient, and for any given admission date per patient, I need to find the next time they were admitted if this was within 30 days of the previosu admission, and the admimeth was in the 20s range, and return that to date to each applicable admission record.

Example:

for this admission I would expect to see the date 2020-08-06 20:14:00.000 repeated across records 1 and 2 below as both the preceding dates were within 30 days and the admimeth was of type 20s

In the table we have data like this:

```
admission, admimeth, admidatetime
530439  12  2020-07-10 08:55:00.000
535686  12  2020-07-31 09:00:00.000
537265  21  2020-08-06 20:14:00.000
```

My SQL currently generates this:

```
admission, admimeth, admidatetime, nextadmdatetime
530439  12  2020-07-10 08:55:00.000 NULL
535686  12  2020-07-31 09:00:00.000 2020-08-06 20:14:00.000
537265  21  2020-08-06 20:14:00.000 NULL
```

The data should look like the below:

```
admission, admimeth, admidatetime, nextadmdatetime
530439  12  2020-07-10 08:55:00.000 2020-08-06 20:14:00.000
535686  12  2020-07-31 09:00:00.000 2020-08-06 20:14:00.000
537265  21  2020-08-06 20:14:00.000 NULL
```

I have tried so far using the row)number() function and doing a datediff, however it doesn't seem the correct approach. This is what I have tried so far:

```
select
[inf].[tbl_ARK2].crn, [inf].[tbl_ARK2].admission, [inf].[tbl_ARK2].admimeth,
case when datediff(d,convert(date,[inf].[tbl_ARK2].disdatetime),convert(date,arkreadm.admidatetime)) <=30 and arkreadm.admimeth like '2%'  then '1' else '0' end [nextadm30],
case when datediff(d,convert(date,[inf].[tbl_ARK2].disdatetime),convert(date,arkreadm.admidatetime)) <=30 and arkreadm.admimeth like '2%'  then arkreadm.admidatetime else NULL end [nextadm30datetime]
from [inf].[tbl_ARK2] 
left join (select 
            crn,admission,[admimeth],admidatetime,disdatetime,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by crn order by convert(date,admidatetime)) [seq]
             from [inf].[tbl_ARK2]
             ) arkreadm
on [inf].[tbl_ARK2].crn = arkreadm.crn
and [inf].[tbl_ARK2].seq = arkreadm.seq-1
```

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `I have a simple query` ... actually your query doesn't look simple at all to me, and without sample data, it may be difficult for anyone here to help you.

Comment: i just provided sample data

Comment: are those sample data from the `tbl_ARK2` or current result from your query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `OUTER APPLY()` and place your condition in the `apply` section

```
select  *
from    yourtable t
        outer apply
        (
            select  x.admidatetime as nextadmdatetime
            from    yourtable x
            where   x.admimeth  like '2%'
            and     x.admidatetime  > t.admidatetime
            and     dateadd(day, 30, t.admidatetime) > x.admidatetime
        ) n
```